# wordpress display date table with inner join and the same variable

Tags: sql, wordpress

Good morning,

In a wordpress page I need to display 2 fields at the same time.
The problem is that I don't know how to display these 2 fields  which have the same title field.

**These 2 fields are called "name" in the my sql table** of Wordpress and are **in 2 separate table.**

I need to display **the name of a book** and **the name of the writer** of the book. So I use `INNER JOIN`to do the link between the two tables but after that I don't know how to display these 2 fields.

```
<?php global $wpdb; $result = $wpdb->get_results
( "SELECT * FROM wp_a INNER JOIN wp_b ON wp_b.id=wp_a.id;"); foreach($result as $row) 
{ echo $row->id."  ".$row->name."  ".$row->name."  ".$row->age."   ; }
?>
```

How to distinguish `".$row->name."` the name of the book  and "`.$row->name."` the writer name ?

Does it exist something like that : `$row->wp_a.name` and `$row->wp_b.name` ?

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the columns you want with an alias

```
SELECT wp_a.name AS a_name FROM wp_a
```

and you can get the value like

```
 $row['a_name']
```

likewise you can select fields from second table